Excel Gantt Chart Drop Down Menus
I am creating a Gantt chart that will encompass all of the marketing activities for my org. My goal is to create a central dashboard that can toggle in between subjects and populate cells based on which topic I have selected. The problem I'm having currently is trying to create a system where the dashboard populates based on what is selected in the drop-down menu (column B). I've explored implementing an x lookup system, but also looking for a simpler method.
In the B column of my excel, I created a data validation list that has "promotions, title releases, and budget planning" There are 4 rows in between each of these subjects. I want the excel sheet to populate with different tasks depending on which subject is selected.
For example, if I select promotions, then the rest of the excel sheet will populate with the details of the various projects. And if I select Title Releases the excel will populate with entirely different information pertaining to the release info.
I've explored implementing an x lookup system but want to explore other options. If also thought about using an "if, then" system as well. I am still relatively new to Excel.
